# Spring/JPA/Hibernate database historical changes at column level

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring/JPA/Hibernate application I need to store all historical changes in my database at column level.

For example I have a table - `users` with a following columns: `id`, `name`, `email`, `address`

For historical changes I'll introduce a new dedicated table, let's say `historical_changes` with a following fields: `id`, `table_name`, `column_name`, `previous_value`, `new_value`.. `create/update_date` and `user_id`

When someone insert/update a record in `users` table I have to add a set of new records to `historical_changes` with an affected columns, for example `users.name` and `users.email` changes have to be logged in a following way:

```
1, 'users', 'name', 'old name', 'new name' ...
2, 'users', 'email', 'old@email.com', 'new@email.com' ...
```

Right now I'm looking for a best way to automate this process. I know that Spring Data supports [Auditing feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) but can't find functionality that allow me to implement the described case.

Please advise me how the described `historical changes` feature can be  implemented with Spring/JPA/Hibernate or may be with some other 3rd party lib.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Comment: @Alan Hay, thanks, but Envers require an additional  table per each entity

Comment: As @AlanHay mentioned, Envers is the best bet for you, which will create additional table (like users_audited) in DB and log every changes made to each row. If you are looking for just log only affected columns, I also don't know of any library. Envers is the most popular for this purpose. However [here](http://jaketrent.com/post/audit-history-hibernate-interceptor/) a very old post uses Hibernate Interceptor, Check if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I will deeply dig into Envers